# Android: How can I open an older android project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm playing around with the new Android Studio IDE, but I'm having problems opening an old android project of mine.  When I go to open the project it is asking for one of the following file formats: `.ipr`, `pom.xml`, `build.gradle`, or `.idea`.  How can I open or convert my old android project so I can open and edit it in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this links.

[How do I open my existing Eclipse projects in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584263/how-do-i-open-my-existing-eclipse-projects-in-android-studio)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: @daveomcd Welcome. Btw you can accept it as an answer if it solved your problem.:)

Comment: I'm on it but it said I had to wait 4 minutes xD

Comment: I've tried exporting the project but cannot. When I click "Finish" nothing ever happens. It's as if the button doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Open Eclipse projects?  I'm having enormous trouble just opening six month old Android Studio projects!  It's actually easier to just start over, cutting and pasting the code than to try to get old versions of gradle and libraries to work again.  Sigh.