# Is there a difference in the android SDKs available for androidStudio and eclipseADT?

Tags: android, android-studio, adt, android-sdk-tools

I am migrating to android Studio from eclipseADT, Can I use the same android sdk's from eclipse?

> I used the following links to migrate:

1. [Exporting from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584263/how-do-i-open-my-existing-eclipse-projects-in-android-studio).
2. [Importing to Android studio.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485981/unable-to-import-eclipse-project-to-android-studio)

Comment: Do you have any particular issue with using 'eclipse' sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also look over this link: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

And yes of course you can use the same android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

SDK stands for Software Development Kit and has nothing to do with the different IDEs(Eclipse, Android Studio) really. The IDE will use the SDK of course but the SDK is unaware of which IDE is using it. You should have no problems with using the same SDK, you just have to set some paths in Android studio.