# Adding external library in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I want to add external library https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth to my Android application (I use Android Studio, the instructions provided by lib author for Eclipse didn't work for Android Studio).

I've tried to do it with maven, so in File->Project Structure->Dependencies I've added `com.foursquare:foursquare-android-nativeoauth-lib:1.0.0` but Gradle Sync fails:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.foursquare:foursquare-android-nativeoauth-lib:1.0.0
```

When I try to build my app (without fixing above error becaus I don't know how) I get:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.foursquare:foursquare-android-nativeoauth-lib:1.0.0.
 Required by:
    ForSquaresOnly:app:unspecified
   > Could not parse POM http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/foursquare/foursquare-android-nativeoauth-lib/1.0.0/foursquare-android-nativeoauth-lib-1.0.0.pom
     > Could not find any version that matches com.foursquare:parent:1.0.0.
```

Any other way to import this lib? I can simply copy-paste source code into my source or create JAR out of it?

BTW: if you run into problems see this question (I had this issue after importing): [Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438170/manifest-merger-failed-uses-sdkminsdkversion-14)

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio http://www.androidsx.com/how-to-link-an-android-library-project-with-gradle-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try this:

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>Dependencies Tab</kbd> > <kbd>Add module dependency</kbd> (`scope = compile`)

Where the module dependency is the project library Android folder.

Comment: it worked, thanks :) I see that when doing what you said Android Studio copies by itself the library to project root directory, is it described somewhere?

Comment: I know it by experience and inspecting.... But there are docs available : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

Comment: How can one do this WITHOUT copying? The library is used by other non-Android projects and is routinely updated. If it copies the source, then changes to the original will not be seen. Isn't that kind of stupid?

Comment: where is Project Structure option ?

Comment: Found ass module dependency but then I got dialog "Choose Modules\nSelect the modules the current module should depend on:\nNothing to show\n[Ok] [Cancel]". Not able to select downloaded library.

Comment: I've added external library this way and got an error "Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@buildTypeUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :zip_file." Generated code in dependency is `
    implementation project(':zip_file')`. Also, I'm using 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-rc03' and https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Comment: What does one need to select before clicking "File" to get "Project Structure" to not be grey/disabled, as it always seems to be for me?

Answer (score 243):

**Try one of these approaches:**

**Approach 1)**

1- Choose project view

[image]

2- Copy your JAR file in app -> lib folder

[image]

3- Right click on your JAR file and choose add as library

[image]
[image]

4- Check it in build.gradle

[image]

---

**Approach 2)**

1- File -> New -> New Module

[image]

2- Import .JAR/.AAR Package

[image]

3- Browse your JAR File

[image]

4- Finish

5- File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies

[image]

6- You should click on + button and then click on Module Dependency

[image]

7- You will see your library here

[image]

8- choose your library and click ok

[image]

9- Then, you will see that your library is added.

[image]

---

**For first two approaches, you need a JAR file. You can search http://search.maven.org/ to find JAR files that are related to Android. For example, this is the search result for jdom in this link**

[image: Search result for jdom]

---

**Approach 3)** Android is using http://jcenter.bintray.com/ as remote library. For example, this is the search result for jdom in the link.

[image: jcenter jdom]

To add a library in this approach, please follow these steps:

1- File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies

[image]

2- Click on + button and choose library dependency

[image]
[image]

3- find your library and select it, then click OK.

Comment: I am glad that you find my answer useful. I really appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Approche 2 works for me. Thanks for the illustrations :)

Comment: I don't get the Add as Library option in step 3 in my Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: In Android studio 3, the project structure's tabs are eliminated!

Comment: Approach 1 appears to be no longer available for Android Studio 4. It may need to be noted to save people from trying it.

Comment: I just followed Approach 1 to add jsch to AS4 @Hong

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone I wonder if it has to do with my use of aar.  Did you use aar or jar?

Comment: @Hong i used jar

Answer (score 46):

To reference an external lib project without copy, just do this:
- Insert this 2 lines on `setting.gradle`:

```
  include ':your-lib-name'
  project(':your-lib-name').projectDir = new File('/path-to-your-lib/your-lib-name)
```

Insert this line on on dependencies part of `build.gradle` file:

```
compile project(':your-lib-name')
```

Sync project

Comment: Great answer, creates a link to the original library, so that you won't have to reimport whenever the library code changed!

Answer (score 25):

There are two simplest ways if one does not work please try the other one.

1. Add dependency of the library inside dependency inside `build.gradle` file of the library you are using,  and paste your library in External Libraries.

OR

2. Just Go to your `libs` folder inside `app` folder and paste all your `.jar` e.g Library files there, Now the trick here is that now go inside `settings.gradle` file now add this line `include ':app:libs'` after `include ':app'` it will definitely  work.

Answer (score 20):

> Any other way to import this lib? I can simply copy-paste source code
>   into my source or create JAR out of it?

Complete Steps for importing a library in Android Studio 1.1

1. Goto File -> Import Module.
2. Source Directory -> Browse the project path.
3. Specify the Module Name
4. Open build.gradle (Module:app) file
5. Add the following line with your module name

   compile project(':internal_project_name')

Taken from: [how to add library in Android Studio](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/)

Answer (score 10):

I had also faced this problem. Those time I followed some steps like:

1. <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>New</kbd> > <kbd>Import module</kbd> > <kbd>select your library_project</kbd>. Then `include 'library_project'` will be added in `settings.gradle` file.
2. <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>App</kbd> > <kbd>Dependencies Tab</kbd> > <kbd>select library_project</kbd>. If `library_project` not displaying then, Click on <kbd>+</kbd> button then select your `library_project`.
3. Clean and build your project. The following lines will be added in your app module `build.gradle` (*hint: this is not the one where `classpath` is defined*).

```
 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile project(':library_project')
 }
```

4. If these lines are not present, you must add them manually and clean and rebuild your project again (<kbd>Ctrl + F9</kbd>).
5. A folder named `library_project` will be created in your app folder.
6. If any icon or task merging error is created, go to `AndroidManifest` file and add `<application tools:replace="icon,label,theme">`

Answer (score 8):

**A late answer, although I thought of giving an in-depth answer to this question. This method is suitable for Android Studio 1.0.0 and above.**

***STEPS***

1. First switch your folder structure from Android to **Project**.

[image]

2. Now search for the **libs folder** inside app - build folder.

[image]

3. Once you have pasted the .jar file inside libs folder. Right click on the jar file and at end click on **Add as library**. This will take care of adding     compile files('libs/library_name.jar') in build.gradle [You don't have to manually enter this in your build file].

[image]

***Now you can start using the library in your project.***

Comment: in my case while using first approach, I did not see add as library option in the list..but second option worked for me. But my question is why add as library option was not shown in my case

Comment: Very helpful Thank you! Note: After updating android studio the "Add As Library" button is no longer at the bottom of the list. It is now about 5th from the bottom.

Answer (score 8):

For the simplest way just follow these steps

1. Go to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>New</kbd> -> <kbd>Import Module</kbd> -> <kbd>choose library or project folder</kbd>
2. Add library to include section in **settings.gradle** file and sync the project (After that you can see new folder with library name is added in project structure)

   `include ':mylibraryName'`
3. Go to File -> Project Structure -> app -> dependency tab -> click on plus button
4. Select module dependency -> select library (your library name should appear there) and put scope (compile or implementation)
5. Add this line in build.gradle in app level module in dependency section

   `implementation project(':mylibraryName')`

Answer (score 7):

Three ways in android studio for adding a external library.

1. if you want to add libarary project dependency in your project :

   A. In file menu click new and choose import module choose your library project path and click ok, library project automatically add in your android studio project .

   B. Now open your main module(like app) gradle file and add project dependency in dependency section dependencies {

   compile project(':library project name')
2. if you want to add jar file :
   A. add jar file in libs folder.
   B. And Add dependency

   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar') // add all jar file from libs  folder, if you want to add particular jar from libs add below dependency.

   compile files('libs/abc.jar')
3. Add Dependency from url (recommended). like

   compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'

Comment: hi vinod, can you please explain how to add the dependency with URL? Also, can it be a git URL which if it undergoes a change gets imported directly into my project? 
I'm a little new to this development so please bear with me if it's a simple question :)

Comment: Hi Nikhil please read android dependency related article that i mention              https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html

Answer (score 4):

Android studio doesn't use `Maven`, it use `Gradle`, you can open your `build.gradle` the route should be: `/app/build.gradle` and add the Gradle dependency that shows on the repo:

The `build.gradle` has a `dependencies` section:

```
dependencies {
    //here add your dependency
}
```

The repo says that you need to add this dependency:

```
compile 'com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3'
```

only add that line to your `dependencies` on `buil.gradle`, save the file, and android will rebuild the project, that's all

Comment: I import external library and it fails to resolve `Failed to resolve: me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.4
<a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
Affected Modules: <a href="openFile:C:/Users/MilaHY/AndroidStudioProjects/DECO3801Proj/DECO3801/app/build.gradle">app</a>` to you have idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

If the library you need is on GitHub then adding it to Android Studio is easy with [JitPack](https://jitpack.io).

Step 1. Add the jitpack repository to build.gradle:

```
allprojects { 
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
  }
}
```

Step 2. Add the GitHub repository as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.github.Username:LibraryRepo:ReleaseTag'
}
```

JitPack acts as a maven repository and can be used much like Maven Central. The nice thing is that the maintainers don't have to upload the library. Behind the scenes JitPack will check out the code from GitHub and compile it. Therefore for this to work there needs to be a working build file in the git repository.

There is also [a guide](https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/) on how to publish an Android library.

Comment: Isn't this going to store dependency files in project tree?

Comment: But I have this error `Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'maven' was added by build file 'app\build.gradle'`

Answer (score 4):

Turn any github project into a single line gradle implementation with this website

https://jitpack.io/

Example, I needed this project:
https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

All I did was paste this into my gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:master-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: You saved me! :) . Thank You, thank You a lot. It is so easy with the trick You said! :I was struggling for near 4 hours, before I see Your answer! :)

Comment: Just FYI: Gradle 4.10 or higher required

Answer (score 2):

There are some changes in new gradle 4.1

instead of compile we should use **implementation**

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

```
1.Goto File -> New -> Import Module
   2.Source Directory -> Browse the project path.
   3.Specify the Module Name – it is used for internal project reference.
```

Open build.gradle (Module:app) file.

```
 implementation project(':library')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This happened because of core library dependency. I was using javax.* . This is what i did to fix

In File->Project Structure->Dependencies I added this as as provided file, not a compile. Then re build the project.

This problem started after upgrade of android studio. But I think it happens when you try to edit you build files manually.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **library** in **Android studio 2.1**

```
Just Go to project -> then it has some android,package ,test ,project view
```

Just change it to **Project View**

under the  `app->lib folder` you can directly copy paste the lib and do android synchronize it. 
That's it

Comment: Copy-Paste the lib? Its a url to a github repo

Answer (score 0):

1)just get your lib from here http://search.maven.org/

2)create a libs folder in app directory

3)paste ur library there

4)right click on ur library and click "Add as Library"

5)thats all u need to do!

I hope this will definitely gonna help you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find any version that matches com.foursquare:parent:1.0.0.

Means that library developer made a mistake in  `.pom` file and specified a wrong one.

I would recommend use the standard approach. You can find [`.pom` file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth/1.1.1/foursquare-android-oauth-1.1.1.pom) in [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth) and use that version or ask developer to take a loot at this problem(via github issue tracker)

```
compile 'com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score -2):

SIMPLE STEPS TO ADD ANY LIBRARY IN ANDROID STUDIO:

1. Copy the file in question from any folder in your computer (eg. C:/documents/xyz.jar"), then go to Android Studio and right-click the Project Library folder and select paste.
2. Now, right click on the newly added Library file and select the option "add as Library"

D.O.N.E