# Android Studio module dependency

Tags: android-studio

I'd like to use a module imported into Android studio in my Android project. My development is taking place in the app module and I have imported sliding-menu as a module and set the dependency in the IDE but gradle cannot find out the dependency and builds fail because of this. How can I tell gradle that I have imported the module?

[image: project screenshot]

Comment: Sandah, buddy did I answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add your dependency as a module, it doesn't mean it is included in your project. You should add it as a library next. Please read "approach 2" part of this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941. It is exactly what you are doing. In this post I explained how to import your JAR files in Android studio and I explained all possible ways step by step with screenshots. I hope it helps.