# Where from dependent jar files are imported during programming in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, jar

While dependencies are added to app's build.gradle in android studio, I want to know if any jar files are downloaded while they are added as external jars?

Where can I find these jars ?

Comment: Goto Project Tool Bar, In Drop Down Select Project->app->intermediates->pre-dexed

Comment: Goto Project Tool Bar, In Drop Down Select Project->app->intermediates->exploded-aar

Comment: I only found com.android.support.support-v4.23.1.1 in the given path

Comment: did you check both places coz in my project files i had jar file in predex

Comment: What do you mean by *added as external jars* ? Are these added in the dependency section of your build.gradle? Or imported using Android Studio menus?

Comment: Did you get your answer Manasa?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can include your JAR files in three different ways. The last one is remote library that is using https://bintray.com/ jcenter online repository. But, if you do it in one of the two other ways, the JAR file will be included physically in your project. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941 for more information. In this post I explained how to import your JAR file in Android studio and I explained all possible ways.

In summary, if it is like this (local address), they are downloaded and these JAR files are physically in the project:

[image]

But, if it is an internet address like this, they are remote libraries (bintray.com jcenter part) and they will be used remotely:

[image]

I hope it helps.