# Android Import library error DefaultGroovyMavenDeveloper

Tags: android, libraries

I'm a newbie android app developer using android studio, and I am trying to use sticky list headers from https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders. I do this by File -> New -> Import Module and I add the dependency. However I am getting the error

```
Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

My project build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testingapp.dylanzammit.com.anothernewproj"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the libraries to your project in Android studio, you can do it in three different ways. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941. In this post I explained how to import your JAR files in Android studio and I explained all possible ways step by step with screenshots. I hope it helps.