# How Do I Include A .jar Library In Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin

Assume that I have no idea what I'm doing.
I'm trying to include a java library that I created in Eclipse with no relation to Android in my Android application so that I can use the classes in said library. I tried creating a folder called "libs" and including ":app:libs" as a dependency in my Project Structure screen under Modules->app->Dependencies. When I try to build, it gives me the message "Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Cannot evaluate module libs : Configuration with name 'default' not found." I looked around and saw that the problem appears to be that I haven't set up a default build configuration for libs. What I can't figure out is how to do this.  How do I set up a default build configuration for the module libs?

Comment: You say you created the java library in Eclipse. Are you also writing your Android app with Eclipse? Or are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Buddy, did you read my post? Did you get your answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in different ways. There are **three standard approaches** for importing a JAR file into Android studio. The first one is **traditional way**, the second one is **standard way**, and the last one is **remote library**. I explained these approaches step by step with screenshots in this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why is **add as library** step necessary?  Shouldn't Gradle just pick up the jars automatically?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to compile your library into a JAR file and then place it in the `libs` (Eclipse) or `app/libs` (Android Studio) folder in your Android project.

Alternatively, if you are using Eclipse to develop your Android app, you can add the library project as a dependency to your Android project. On the other hand, if you are using Android Studio, you can import the code for your library as a module and add it as a dependency to the module for your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to add a jar dependency to a Gradle build of an Android app. You can create a folder called libs in your app project, but to tell Gradle to include jars from that folder, you'll have to put a line like this in your dependencies block:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

If you create a new Android project from scratch in Android studio, this line is actually present for you in the template it uses.

The syntax you were using for ':app:libs' is actually telling gradle you want to add a dependency on subproject of 'app' called 'libs'.  Time to hit the gradle docs...

Comment: No, this doesn't compile the jar file for me.