# Migrate Eclipse app and libs to Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, libs

I have an Android **app** project in eclipse that references to 3 **libs**+ some **jar** files and I would like to migrate all to Android studio.

First, I export "generate Gradle build files" (app) and succeed import in Android Studio.

I tried to create root folder manualy but the Imports in the App "cannot resolve symbol .."
How do I migrate the rest libs and jars and implement them?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio

Comment: Did you get your answer buddy?

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the rest of your libs and jars to Android studio, you can do it in three different ways. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941. In this post I explained how to import your JAR files in Android studio and I explained all possible ways step by step with screenshots. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No need to export your project in android studio manage itself ,

1. open android studio and select import project (eclipse adt etc)
2. browse to your project root directory and pick your main project not
   library or dependent project .
3. start wizard to import and wait to complete gradle build.