# How to import android project from Eclipse to Android studio?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to migrate my old android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. I followed step by step many tutorials. But I cannot find any solution to add Gradle files and Gradle dependencies to my project which is imported. I use android studio 3.0.1 and Eclipse Luna.

I did "Import Project(Gradle, Eclipse ADT, etc)" from Android studio Home Screen and then Android studio did some stuff to convert and etc. But when I want to run my project there are no gradle files.

Comment: I'd suggest you copy-paste the old java codes in java side of Android studio and then, paste the values, styles and etc either and after that, look for needed dependencies which you have used for Eclipse and trying to find the similiar for Android studio.

Comment: Try this link: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate#import_eclipse_projects_to_android_studio

Comment: @Mohsen There is no "Automatic" and "easier" way to do that?

Comment: There is, but in what cost? it will be a messy project and might have several errors and etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrate Eclipse app and libs to Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450972/migrate-eclipse-app-and-libs-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open the project in android studio and when the android studio prompts to update gradle. Just click **Don't update gradle for this project**. And sit back. Your project will be imported successfully.