# Error including library htmlCleaner

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android developing whith Android Studio.
I'm trying to include the htmlcleaner library in my project, but when I rebuild the project, Android Studio return this Error

Error: COnfiguration whit name 'default' not found

I added in the root folder of my project the library folder, so I added this line in settings.gradle
include ':htmlcleaner'

and this line in build.gradle
compile project (':htmlcleaner')

Is there anyone who can help me? thanks

to include many informations, I post the build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rob_company_domain.sunshine"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),            'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project (':htmlcleaner')

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your htmlcleaner library to your project in Android studio, you can do it in three standard ways. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941. In this post I explained how to import your JAR files in Android studio and I explained all possible ways step by step with screenshots. I hope it helps.

Comment: You are welcome buddy. Please up-vote my answer if it is useful for you.