# How to add external library in android studio

Tags: addition, external

I am fresher in android and trying to add external library in android studio. Can any one tell me how to add this in details ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding external library in Android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio)

Comment: Buddy, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 3):

i resolved it please follow this...

firstly go in File---> New--> Import module--> than Select External library Folder like FFMPEG(i used it in my project) from your Computer. after that it will be added in same hierarchy of your Project, after again go into the File-->Project Structure-->app--> dependencies--> click on plus icon -->select 3).Module Dependencies Now in your list its been shown your Library select it

this solution is working for me if not solved than please tell me i can help you if possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add external library to your project in Android studio, you can do it in three standard ways. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/5475941. In this post I explained how to import your JAR files in Android studio and I explained all possible ways step by step with screenshots. I hope it helps.