# unable to import a project from github in zip format to android studio

Tags: android

i had to import an existing project in android form github(zip).
i downloaded it extracted the folder to desktop then in the file option in android tried to import it using import settings options but it is showing this error

""Cannot find file 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\ud839_Miwoka6df7e73966c65594ae4c35c89b3e691d0fe9c44\settings.jar' . i checked on the  stackoverflow itself, the steps are right but they are not working for me can someone help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/1466287

Comment: it is not a library it is a whole app actually, it is a project from udacity android multiscreen course it contains some startup work but then yout eventually need to complete it.

Comment: https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/a6df7e73966c65594ae4c35c89b3e691d0fe9c44 link to gihub

Comment: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud839/lessons/7633778648/concepts/75563354820923# this is where they show how to doit.