# How do I add this file as a library in android studio

Tags: android

I am following a guidebook to start learning android studio, but I just got stuck in the library part.

I am given the following [link](https://github.com/twitter-university/YambaClientLib)

Since the guidebook is using eclipse and I am now using android studio, I do not understand how to import it?

Your answer will help me a big deal! please!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Comment: I add libraries using cradle (look for the gradle dependendecy and add them to cradle --> build, and your done

Comment: i think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25612132/6756523) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/6756523) should help