# How can i add library in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I want add this library into my application : https://github.com/pucamafra/android-segmentedtab

I added this **dependences** `compile 'com.marlonmafra.android.widget:segmented-tab:1.1.0'` in **build.gradle** and added this code again in **build.gradle**

`repositories {
    jcenter()
}`

but when click on sync, not sync project and show me this error :

```
        Error:(125, 10) Failed to resolve: com.marlonmafra.android.widget:segmented-tab:1.1.0
   Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

Error image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne0oq.jpg

How can i fix it?

Comment: check this already answered http://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/2784663

Answer (score 0):

Add it in -> build.gradle(Module: app)

Comment: How can i fix it? can you help me step by step?

Comment: Under -> Gradle Scripts

Comment: open -> build.gradle(Module: app) 
In that under dependencies add -> compile 'com.marlonmafra.android.widget:segmented-tab:1.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Open your project in Android Studio
2. Download the library (using Git, or a zip archive to unzip)
3. Create a folder "subProject" in your project
4. Copy and paste the FreemiumLibrary folder to your subProject folder
5. On the root of your project directory create/modify the settings.gradle file.It should contain something like the following:

   include 'MyApp', ':subProject:FreemiumLibrary'

   1. gradle clean & build/close the project and reopen/re-import it.
   2. Edit your project's build.gradle to add this in the "depencies" section:

      dependencies {
      //...
          compile project(':subProject:FreemiumLibrary')
      }

Comment: let me know if you get success

Comment: @user7121617 sorry i cant get you

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file just write this line in dependencies

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.marlonmafra.android.widget:segmented-tab:1.1.0'
}
```

Then rebuild your project. build->rebuild project.

Comment: Before send your answer please read my question! i try this way but show me error again