# How to integrate liblinphone library into my existing android studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I want to integrate liblinphone library with my android studio project and I went through the official documentation provided by Liblinphone developers.
I have cloned the liblinphone project from git repository.When I am trying to import that cloned project into android studio, It is not importing.

I have searched a lot but didn't get any proper solution for this.If anyone did this liblinphone integration please guide me. [This is the link I am referring](https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-android)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

- Navigate to the liblinphone website
  http://www.linphone.org/
- Search for the liblinphone page and go to downloads
  http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads
- Download the liblinphone android sdk
  [image: liblinphone download page]
- Open your android project (I assume you already have an android project)
- In android studio: file->new->new module
- Select import .JAR/.AAR Package
  [image: android studio add module]
- Select the .aar from your liblinphone-android-sdk (see image above for reference)
  [image: Select aar]
- After your done importing the package go to File->Project Structure in Android Studio and add a module dependency to your project
- [image: Project structure add module dependency]
- Select :liblinphone-android-sdk
- You should now be able to use the functionality the library provides
  [image: example]

  **See also [this explanation on how to add external libraries in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio)**

Comment: Best answer, Thanks for this.

Comment: @jouke I agree with pulkit. This is "the" best answer I have found so far on the internet. However, I have few questions. I have seen some questions asking for integrating linphone to existing android app. 1. What is the difference? 2. If I integrate liblinphone in my existing app, do I need a voip server to make audio video calls within app?