# Adding external dependent jars in android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, jar

I'm trying to add external jars to my android project. these external jars are dependent on each other and some them are dependencies to another one so when there is a reference to a class which is located in another jar file android studio throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for that class.

what's the right solution to use these kind of jars in an android project??

```
  compile files('libs/gt-shapefile-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-metadata-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-data-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-main-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-api-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-referencing-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/vecmath-1.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-opengis-2.7.5.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar')
compile files('libs/jts-1.11.jar')
compile files('libs/jdom-1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/jai_core-1.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar')
compile files('libs/gt-epsg-hsql-2.7.5.jar')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35241990/7592874) answer to get the right way to add jar libraries.

> 1. First switch your folder structure from Android to Project. enter
>      image description here [image]
> 2. Now search for the libs folder inside app - build folder.
>      [image]
> 3. Once you have pasted the .jar file inside libs folder. Right click on
>      the jar file and at end click on Add as library. This will take care
>      of adding compile files('libs/library_name.jar') in build.gradle [You
>      don't have to manually enter this in your build file]. enter image
>      description here
>
>    [image]
>
>    Now you can start using the library in your project.

Comment: and you can refer to this answer which include many approuches.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/7592874

Comment: i did it and there was no result and getting same error

Comment: @alirezarahmaty I think you should make sure that the libraries are also implemented inside the other libraries.