# How install and use library android

Tags: java, android

I would like to use librares in android studio I import module and I don't know what to do later. 
There's librares https://github.com/feicien/android-auto-update
https://github.com/mitmel/AppUpdateChecker

How make this working ? Instructions there are a bit weak.

Comment: how new is android development to you? i dont think you need these at all. They seem VERY easy to do yourself.

Comment: What have you achieved so far? Can you clarify what practices you have tried and failed? How do they stand comparing to existing similar questions? How do they compare to the Android documentation?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very popular question, you could easily find an answer to this everywhere, for instance:

[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Adding external library in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio)

Long story short:

Try this:

File > Project Structure > Dependencies Tab > Add module dependency (scope = compile)

Where the module dependency is the project library android folder