# Android Studio can't see imports

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've just built my project in Android Studio and now it doesn't see my imports in `MainActivity` class. It worked before. These classes that I want to import are in the library folder. Do I need to change something in the Gradle files?

Error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'TSChannel'.
```

Comment: probably related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682847/how-to-manually-include-external-aar-package-using-new-gradle-android-build-syst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio)
You should insert the jar, right click and select `Add As Library...` 
and `Check it in build.gradle`.