# In Android Studio, how to edit package source code?

Tags: android

I used this ShadowView in my project.[github: loopeer shadow](https://github.com/loopeer/shadow)

And method `setBackgroundClr()` doesn't work. This issue provides solution: [issue 19](https://github.com/loopeer/shadow/issues/19)

I need to add a method `setBackgroundCls()` to class ShadowView. I know source code cannot be directly edited. So downloaded zip file, made changes and re-imported this package.

I followed this solution [Adding external library in Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369267/9478153) but it doesn't work.

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio) simple explanation maybe it's helpful for you

Comment: do you add 'shadow' as module dependency ?