# Android - Protecting my App from changes/deletion of an external GitHub Library?

Tags: android, github, repository, android-library

I'm using a Library found on GitHub in my App, and I have a concern..
**When compiling/Publishing to the PlayStore, how do I protect from Library changes?



In other words, which of the following are true?**

**(A)** - Does it continue calling code from the repository itself, even once it's on the PlayStore?
(or)
**(B)** - Does it compile the Library code into my App, prior to being Published?
(or)
**(C)** - Should I download the Library myself and include it in my package first, prior to Publishing?

I simply want to protect my App, in the event that the Library gets **changed** or **deleted** somehow..
I apologize in advance, as I'm still learning this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Option "C" seems way tedious, besides if library is unpublished let's assume that the author has good reason.

Answer (score 1):

A - Yes, unless you include it in the library in your own app.
B - Yes
C - Yes if you would like to keep the library in-app.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio) it might help.

Comment: I interpret question A as _"If I build against library X, will it fetch code from X's repository **at runtime** and execute that?"_. To which I would answer _"Very unlikely, but not impossible"_.

Comment: @ryan-godlonton-shaw Let me rephrase my Question: Should I download the Libraries I use in my App, and import them manually, before I publish the App? (in order to protect myself in case the Library gets changed by the original author, or deleted somehow)..?

Comment: Yes you should. :)

Comment: Create an AAR or JAR file.

Comment: @Michael I'm simply trying to make sure the Libraries I'm using in my App (which I'm currently including by using `implement` (formerly `compile`) followed by the appropriate Library name/repo, in my build file), doesn't somehow get  **changed** or **deleted** after I publish my App.. So I'm just trying to make sure I understand how this all works.. Do I need to download and import the raw Library files/code into my App manually, prior to publishing my App, instead of using the build file to `implement`/`compile` the repo?

Comment: @RyanGodlonton-Shaw Ok great, thank you for the answer! So I assume I can download the AAR or JAR file from the Library's GitHub repository, correct? And then do I just simply Import it from within Android Studio's file menu, and it's good to go? And I can then delete the `implement` or `compile` lines from the Build file right?

Comment: @ryan-godlonton-shaw If the Library on GitHub doesn't list any links for an AAR/JAR file to be downloaded, could you tell me how to create an AAR/JAR file for the Library I'm using, in such a case? I apologize if this is a common task, I'm fairly new to this, since I've always just "compile" or "implement"-ed the Library. But now that I'm Publishing for the first time, I need to know how to actually include the Library code in my App itself. Please and thank you.