# Outdated version of GitHub project loading in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, universal-image-loader

I'm trying to use a library from GitHub in my Android Studio Project (specifically, the Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

My project has been crashing, due to an error with a variable called *mMaxHeight*, in a file called **ImageViewAware.java**

On the GitHub page, I see that this issue was 4 fixed months ago:
[image]

When I view the code in **ImageViewAware.java** on GitHub, I see that the issue is fixed.

However when I look at the version of **ImageViewAware.java** being used in my Android Studio, I see it's an older version, with the issue not fixed.

I've added

```
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
```

to my Gradle Dependency, as the documentation says, and have followed all other instructions I can see.

I notice that the last update to those instructions was over a year ago.  Should I be implementing a newer version than 1.9.5?  Is there another reason why the version in my Android Studio isn't getting the latest GitHub version?

I'm pretty new to this and feeling a bit out of my depth.  Thanks for any help!

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correctly using the latest published version of the library, v1.9.5.

However, there have been 23 unreleased commits to that library since then, as shown on [the GitHub tags page](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/releases/tag/v1.9.5):

[image: v1.9.5 release notes]

To get the latest version of the code, you'll need to:

1. [Download the library's zip](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/archive/master.zip).
2. Unzip it.
3. [Manually add the dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio) to your project.

This process is pretty straightforward, you may also be interested in [this list of every difference between v1.9.5 and master](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/compare/v1.9.5...master).

---

**However**, I'd recommend *against* using this library if possible, given that it hasn't had a release / major update in 4.5 years! In the readme the author states he has stopped maintaining it. It also has over [400 open issues](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues), despite the popularity.

More modern libraries like [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) are much more widely supported, feature rich, and reliable.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll fix up UVI  for now, then migrate to Glide on the next draft of my app