# Android Repository not working in library module

Tags: android, dependencies, repository, libs

I have got a project with app module and a library module. The app module can import library module properly. But the weird thing happens when I tried to get dependencies inside library module by declaring repository inside it. The repository closure in library module doesn't work at all, which means I can't read aar from library libs folder or get dependencies from the designated URL. Am I doing anything wrong?

project strucutre:

```
->App
  ->libs
  ->src
->LibraryModule
  ->libs // aar placed here
  ->src
```

build.gradle in library module:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } // can not find URL here
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'. // can not find libs folder in library module
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    Implementation(name: 'testing', ext: 'aar') // Not working because libs folder in library module can not be found.
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your library module in `settings.gradle` file? The file is located in the root of your project and you need to add the library there. you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610727/adding-external-library-in-android-studio) too

Comment: please see the updated question. The library module is imported properly, this is a problem of library module itself.

Comment: The same with me, I've tried to disable the repository setting in settings.gradle and add allprojects {} block in the project build.gradle. Nothing works :(