# using eclipese project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to use an external eclipse project in android studio. I did n't find any nice tutorial. 
"Also the docs says, If you want to import this project in Android studio, here you can download build.gradle."

Can you please guide me where/how to use this [build.gradle](http://csform.com//wp-content/uploads/2015/01/build.gradle)?

Step by step procedure will be appreciated?

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791150/how-do-you-import-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio-now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584263/how-do-i-open-my-existing-eclipse-projects-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Android Studio.

- Click 'File'.
- Click 'Import Project'.
- Choose the project to import.
- It will ask for a destination to save the project as Android
  Studio's.
- Save it and it will automatically convert the project

Answer (score 1):

Android Developers website has a quick [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

General Android Studio information is available [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).