# Import Project from ADT (eclipse Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

When i try to import an existing project in android studio for development, I get the following error.

*** Project NiuDrawingKit:D:\Android\Projects...*ProjectName*...\NiuDrawingKit\project.properties:
Library reference ....\Desktop\HoloColorPicker-master could not be found
Path is D:\Android\Projects...*ProjectName*...\NiuDrawingKit....\Desktop\HoloColorPicker-master which resolves to D:\Android\Projects...*ProjectName*...\Desktop\HoloColorPicker-master***

This project was developed long ago in eclipse. I also find that the particular lib "NiuDrawingKit" cant be found by android studio.

any support to resolve this issue?
Other than this lib, project also uses JakeWharton-ViewPagerIndicator and google-play-sevrvices_lib..which is found to be no issues.

Comment: is this eclipse project?

Comment: if you're trying to import eclipse project then here's your [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16584503/4647628) :)

Comment: Actually app was developed long back before gradle was introduced. Therefore, export from eclipse was done without gradle. That's why we are facing the above mentioned problem.