# Is there any way to create Twitter Share dialog like FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder?

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter

I am using `Eclipse` editor.

I know about `Twitter` integration using Fabric in `Android studio`.

But that is not useful for me because of `Eclipse`.

I want to know is there any way to create `Twitter` share dialog like `FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder`

Comment: Jump to `Android Studio`. It's fastest and best solution...

Comment: No I can't because I am working in this project since last 6-7 month.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

#### [Fabric in Eclipse](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html)

by the way as commented by [MD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114338/m-d) You have to Jump to **Android Studio**

> With the recent announcement [Google made about dropping support for Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html), after much thought, we’ve decided to discontinue future support for Eclipse as well. Although we’re no longer going to be rolling out any more upgrades to Eclipse, your existing plugin for Eclipse and dashboard will continue to work.

Thank you.

Comment: I use this tutorial http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-twitter-integration.html# and that fulfill me requirement. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

As you said

> working in this project since last 6-7 month.

but consider [Pratik's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333348/3134215) answer, you can use [FABRICS in Eclipse](https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html) but it will be wise decision to move to AS to use all the available features

Regarding migrating from Eclipse to AS it's very easy, you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22797387/3134215)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16584503/3134215)

Comment: I know about Fabric in eclipse, But as @PratikButani said Fabric drop support for eclipse.

Comment: yes that's why i said it will be wise decision to move to AS

Comment: I use this tutorial http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-twitter-integration.html# and that fulfill me requirement. Thanks for help.