# How to import eclipse project into android studio?

Tags: android, gradle

Under File menu in android studio 2.1.2 I see no import but import setting. However, and obviously import setting won't allow me to import a project. So I tried opening eclipse project from File menu open in android studio but then it says "This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system." So how do I import if there is no import option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open my existing Eclipse projects in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584263/how-do-i-open-my-existing-eclipse-projects-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

close your project first File -> Close project. Then on Main screen you will see option Import project(Eclipse ADT,Gradel,etc ). Choose this option to import your eclipse project. And then follow instructions as directed.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am new to android studio. It work after closing the project.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried closing all projects and following **import projects**?
[image: screen]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It work now after closing the project.

Answer (score 3):

close existing open project and then You got dialog from that you choose below option for import eclipse project to android studio

> Import project(Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc) options

For eg: check image [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the path from the menu (without closing existing projects):

File> New> Import Project...